# Need help rewriting "Transp 0 : 100"

Tags: colors, pine-script, transparency

as everyone probably knows "Transp = is being deprecated"
I am aware of how to rewrite color.new and recode that part.

However, in a different section of a pine script I see `transp = lines? 0 : 100` which in the script then allows the color and slider bar to be manipulated.

Can anyone help point me to where I can find how to rewrite this portion of the pine-script?

Thank you in advance

here are images of how the old and new code show up (old is colorful and optional, new is B/W)

[image: Old #1]

[image: Old #2]

[image: New just BW]

Answer (score 0):

transp == lines  ? color.new(color.blue,100) : color.new(color.blue,10)

Its all about the condition, if it's true then trans will be 100, if not then Tran will be 10. Change trans to your liking

You can post full code and I'll correct if you not able to do it

Comment: AMAZING!!
Thanks! I'll try that now

Comment: Hi sir- still having an issue and came to work on this a bit and was not able to fix the problem. currently the script works, its just that im afraid if Transp is deprecated it will be a hassle later so why not address it now.

full script is long and cannot attach in limited char here. 
Ill post a section next of the problem area

When I use your suggestion, I get a syntax error I cannot correct for the life of me

Comment: p1 = plot(a, linewidth = 2, transp = lines? 0 : 100,color = color.green ,title = "Ema 1")
p2 = plot(b, linewidth = 2, transp = lines? 0 : 100,color = color.blue ,title = "Ema 2")
p3 = plot(c, linewidth = 2, transp = lines? 0 : 100, color = color.orange,title = "Ema 3")
p4 = plot(d, linewidth = 4, transp = lines? 0 : 100,color = color.yellow, title = "Ema 4")
barcolor(candle_color ? close > high_band ? color.green : close < low_band? color.red : color.black : na)